# How to use - SPUtility.GetSPField to set date

Tags: custom-form, date-time, list-form, date, sputility

The script does not work. I have to write the date value in the field (I tried to do both a regular text field and a Date field) Date2 As it seems to me because of the wrong name. But maybe something else.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var dat = new Date();
      document.writeln(dat);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var dateValue= SPUtility.GetSPField('Date2').SetValue(dat);
    });
    </script>
```

At the moment there is this usual representation of the LIST. It has columns with the name, date of creation, notes and date2 (it was planned that the column would be hidden).

I add the script through the implementation of the code. At first I did everything according to the instructions - but there was no result.

[image]

Comment: What is the display name of your field?

Comment: Date2  - Plain text box.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing the wrong field name in your code.

**Note**:

In order to get the field using `SPUtility`, the field should be available on list form. **You cannot get the field on list form using `SPUtility` if it is hidden from Content Type**.

**Solution**:

1. Do not make your fields hidden from content type settings.
2. Use below codes to first set the value in your field and then make them hidden using `SPUtility`.

According the documentation given at: [SPUtility - Common SPField functions](https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility/blob/master/WikiFiles/docs/Common%20SPField%20functions.md),

> - **SPUtility.GetSPField(strFieldName)** - Get a field on DispForm, EditForm, or NewForm by the field's display name. Returns an SPField object.
> - **SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName(strFieldName)** - Get a field by its internal column name. Returns an SPField object.

1. In `GetSPField()` method you need to pass the **Display name** of your field (Which you can see in the list form or list view).
2. In `GetSPFieldByInternalName()` method you need to pass the **[Internal name](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)** of your field.

**Set Single Line of Text Field**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date = new Date();
        var dateString = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();   //dd/mm/yyyy format
        SPUtility.GetSPField('Date2').SetValue(dateString);
    });
</script>
```

**Set Date & Time Field**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date = new Date();
        SPUtility.GetSPField('Date2').SetDate(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate());
    });
</script>
```

**Hide a field from list form**:

```
SPUtility.GetSPField('Date2').Hide();
```

Assuming, where **Date2** is display name of your field.

**Update from Comments**:

Follow below steps:

1. Upload `jQuery` and `SPUtility` files into a Document Library (Probably Site Assets) in your SharePoint site.
2. Edit the SharePoint form you wish to modify and add a Content Editor Web Part with the following script inside of it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SiteName/SiteAssets/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SiteName/SiteAssets/sputility.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       // TODO: Your scripts go here!

       // EXAMPLE: Set the value of the Title field to Hello world!
       SPUtility.GetSPField('Title').SetValue('Hello world!');
    });
</script>
```

**Reference**: [SPUtility - Usage](https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility#usage).

Comment: Thanks.
But it didn’t work. do not understand why.
Created a new column in the same test list. Just named differently. In the scripts you proposed, the name changed accordingly.
In the debugger, it produces the same error.
~sputility.min.js:10 Uncaught Unable to get a SPField named Data2

Comment: There are scripts for testing on the utility site. Do you think it makes sense, and how, to launch?

Comment: How you are adding this code in your list form? Are you referencing jQuery or SP Utility files multiple times on your page? Also try to create a new single line text with simple name like "MyTextField"(without spaces), do not make it hidden, do not change its display name and then check getting the field using above code. And then try setting its value or making it hidden.

Comment: I connect the script as in the instructions. link to the jquery + link to the utility. after the script itself.
This is all adding to the page. A page of type List, and I add it through the "Web Part" - "Script Editor".
I refresh the page (f5) and look in the debugger, which confirms that there is an error

Comment: You need to add the reference to jQuery and SPUtility files before this code. and make sure this files are loading properly from `Sources` tab in browser --> Next to Console tab. also, which instructions you followed? any reference link?

Comment: saw in one source. BUT when it didn’t work, I looked if I connected the script correctly her https://github.com/kitmenke/sputility
I admit, I added the script through the web part of the "Script Editor". Because adding by "Adding content" it will ruin the script (I did not check this)

Comment: Check update answer on how to use SPUtility

Comment: made an experiment. Created a new page. And a few lines. Added a script there. I copied (for reliability) from here. And so what happened ..
https://imageup.ru/img227/3548320/bygnow.png.html

Comment: Sorry for being rude. And nobody ever did that, ever? Did it work for you?

Comment: By looking at the image in your above comment, I can see that you have added the code in list view. But in order to set the field value you need to add this code in list new form/edit form and not on list view page.

Comment: Go to your list --> Click on **LIST** from top riibon --> Click on **Forms Web Parts** under **Customize List** section --> Select **Default New Form** or **Default New Form** --> When new page opens select Gear(settings) icon --> Edit Page --> Add Webpart --> Use content editor/script webpart --> add your code in it.

Comment: You can set value in column from list forms and list views.

Comment: It's fair to say. I am stuck. The first one. When executing the script, it comes to a certain point, and gives the value of the field:  **_fieldsHashtable   undefined**
  As it seems to me (at the moment) the main problemma. Because the value of the date itself, the script receives. Further errors appear.
I found some developer records for this module. I tried to fulfill what he advises - it did not work for me. after that, he ceased to understand what was happening. And will it work?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Especially thanks Ganesh Sanap. It worked for me. Carefully rechecked all the conditions. It worked for me on the page "NewForm.aspx"

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.
This will help other users to find the correct answer easily in future.